# Freezing Python program - Imports are always skipped

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, py2app

I've been trying for a few days to freeze a Python program. I've tried py2app, PyInstaller and cx_freeze. Of all 3, cx_freeze seemed to be the most effective.

py2app and PyInstaller seems to skip all my imports whichever settings I'm using. The modules needed are always found in "Modules not found (unconditional imports)" with py2app. With PyInstaller, everything seems to run fine, but the program fails to launch due to the fact that no modules is imported, even when specified as hidden import.

For cx_freeze, some imports seems to be done, as it is at least trying to import PyQt5.

But cx_freeze failed at this step with this error:

```
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile

    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore'
```

For information:

Python version: 3.7.2, installed with Anaconda3.

List of imports:

```py
import sys

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
```

OS used: MacOS 10.11.16

Targeted OS for freezing: MacOS (various versions)

At this point, I don't really know what to do to freeze my programe. If anyone has an idea, that would be awesome.